# Drinking and eating ability of infants soon after birth

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience

How do infants know how to eat, drink without being taught? How do they get this ability soon after birth?

Comment: It's called instinctual behavior. And they have very, very many abilities after birth: the ability to swim (rudimentarily, not like Michael Phelps), take steps on a hard surface, to cry, to open their eyes, etc., etc.

Comment: These are just reflexes which are executed involuntarily, they need not to be learned , but are present naturally in the neural circuitry.